# How to migrate to a larger sd card

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, app2sd

I am using a rooted fire tablet and have some apps installed on a 4GB sd card. 
How can I migrate to a larger sd card? Will cloning and expanding the partition with gparted work?

I'm familiar with Linux and external storage is mounted via UUID. So I was afraid of just copy and paste, because that doesn't copy the UUID.

Duplicate, but no satisfying answer: [Changing SD Card Just a Simple Copy & Paste](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/13638/173477)

Comment: You mean adopt the storage?

Comment: @user4847410 I want to move my data to a larger sd card

Comment: I'm assuming the SD card is removable? Take it out and copy everything onto a computer with hidden files toggled then copy it onto your new SD card. That should work

Comment: @Motte001 I suggest a /data/media partition

Comment: If you're talking about a physical SD card: simply shutdown your device, copy *all* contents of its SD card to the new card, put the new card in, boot it up. If unsure whether that works without issues, take a look at our [external-sd tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/external-sd/info) and follow up to the question linked at its bottom :)

Comment: @Izzy that worked. Post it as answer please

Comment: As indicated in my previous comment, the answer is already posted here: [How do I switch my Android device's SD card without causing problems?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17402/16575) As we don't duplicate answers, and question as well as answer match, I'll close your question now as duplicate to that. It's the cleaner way :)